# Website works with half my webscraping code but other half gives an error message

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, blocked

I am new to web scraping and am  having a hard time figuring out how to manage an issue: The website I am scraping is cooperating with half my code but now for the other half.
I am scraping data from mmadecisions.com with the below crawling code. I pull out the first page links successfully, then open the pages of those links successfully, but when I get to the third 'layer' it gives me an error. Is it javascript? It's odd because when I input the href link to the 'get_single_item_data' function, it runs perfectly. does that mean I should use selenium? Is it a block from the website? Then why is half the scraping working (for the http://mmadecisions.com/decisions-by-event/2013/ & http://mmadecisions.com/decision/4801/John-Maguire-vs-Phil-Mulpeter) as you can see in my output below where I've gotten the href links printed before getting to the third layer.:

```
import requests

 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 import time

    my_headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"}

    def ufc_spider(max_pages):
        page = 2013
        while page <= max_pages:
            url = 'http://mmadecisions.com/decisions-by-event/'+str(page)+'/'
            print(url)
            source_code = requests.get(url, headers=my_headers)
            plain_text = source_code.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")    
            data = soup.findAll('table',{'width':'100%'})[2]
            for link in data.findAll('a', href=True):
                href = 'http://mmadecisions.com/' + str(link.get('href'))
                source_code = requests.get(href, "html.parser")
                plain_text = source_code.text
                soup2 = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
                tmp = []
                other = soup2.findAll('table',{'width':'100%'})[1]
                for con in other.findAll('td', {'class':'list2'}):
                    CON = con.a
                    ahref = 'http://mmadecisions.com/' + str(CON.get('href'))
                    print(ahref)
                    time.sleep(5)

                    get_single_item_data(ahref)


            page += 1    



    def get_single_item_data(item_url):
        tmp = []
        source_code = requests.get(item_url, headers=my_headers)
        time.sleep(10)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        print(soup)


    ufc_spider(2017)
```

This is the output where I am able to get the website urls **but it won't let me get the data from the second url**:

```
http://mmadecisions.com/decisions-by-event/2013/
http://mmadecisions.com/decision/4801/John-Maguire-vs-Phil-Mulpeter

<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu) - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /decision/4801/John-Maguire-vs-Phil-Mulpeter%0D%0A</h1><hr noshade="noshade" size="1"/><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/decision/4801/John-Maguire-vs-Phil-Mulpeter%0D%0A</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><hr noshade="noshade" size="1"/><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu)</h3></body></html>
http://mmadecisions.com/decision/4793/Amanda-English-vs-Slavka-Vitaly

<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu) - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /decision/4793/Amanda-English-vs-Slavka-Vitaly%0D%0A</h1><hr noshade="noshade" size="1"/><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/decision/4793/Amanda-English-vs-Slavka-Vitaly%0D%0A</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><hr noshade="noshade" size="1"/><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu)</h3></body></html>
http://mmadecisions.com/decision/4792/Chris-Boujard-vs-Peter-Queally
......
```

I have tried to change the user agent header, I've tried to do a time delay, and I've run the code with my VPN. None are working and all are giving the same output.
Please help!

Comment: It isn’t very clear what the issue is, nor what you have done to try to solve it. Please see: [ask], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11301900, https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = []
for item in range(2013, 2020):
    print(f"{'-'*30}Extracting Year# {item}{'-'*30}")
    r = requests.get(f"http://mmadecisions.com/decisions-by-event/{item}/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}):
        item = item.get('href')
        if item.startswith('event'):
            print(f"http://mmadecisions.com/{item}")
            links.append(f"http://mmadecisions.com/{item}")

print("\nNow Fetching all urls inside Years..\n")

for item in links:
    r = requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.findAll('a', {'href': True}):
        item = item.get('href')
        if item.startswith('decision/'):
            print(f"http://mmadecisions.com/{item}".strip())
```

Run Code Online: [Click Here](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/Viva)

Note that you can use the following:

```
for item in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'list'}):
    for an in item.findAll('a'):
        print(an.get('href'))
```

And

```
for item in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'list2'}):
    for an in item.findAll('a'):
        print(an.get('href').strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me a more eloquent way of web crawling! Wow! What I have took me a few weeks to build. However, I cannot seem to get the right 'soup' of the webpages:

Comment: Thank you for showing me a more eloquent way of web crawling! What I have took me a few weeks to build. But, your correction still doesn't get the right 'soup' of the webpages. I added a few lines to your code in order to get to last page level to get the data (judge ratings). The error is still coming up:


pages = []
for item in links:
........(your code)...............
            pages.append(f"http://mmadecisions.com/{item}")

for item in pages:
    r = requests.get(item)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)

Comment: I've tested the code online and it's works without any issue !https://repl.it/@AmericanY/Viva

Comment: The problem I have is that I cannot get the proper 'soup' of the last layer of web page (example: http://mmadecisions.com/decision/4801/John-Maguire-vs-Phil-Mulpeter). I updated the link you posted with my final layer that I am having issues with. Can you see it?

Comment: @Viva that's completely different than your question at all ! We've scraped all `years events` and all `decision`. now you want to access each `decision` ?

Comment: If you test my code, the urls work (though extremely bulky compared to yours). The problem is the final 'layer' If you read my explanation, I shared that my code is half working. The final most crucial portion is the decisions data, but the soup is not coming out right. If I input a url manually, it works and i can extract data. Please help!

Comment: @Viva looks like you did not understand what am talking about. anyway. for the previous link which you've shared ! what you want to extract from it ?

Comment: I need to extract judges and their scores.. I have the html code for that, but when i print the soup to check, it gives me the error I shared in my question. I really appreciate your help! This has been driving me crazy..

Comment: @viva give me example of expected output for http://mmadecisions.com/decision/4801/John-Maguire-vs-Phil-Mulpeter

Comment: REFEREE: Marc Goddard
John Maguire
Phil Mulpeter
December 31, 2013
CWFC 63: Cage Warriors 63
Unanimous Decision
Maguire defeats Mulpeter


Judge 1
Ben Cartlidge
Judge 2
David Lethaby
Judge 3
Barry Oglesby
----------------JUDGE 1 ROUND 1---------------
Round 1
Maguire
9
Mulpeter
10
----------------JUDGE 1 ROUND 2---------------
Round 2
Maguire
10
Mulpeter
9
....(contd)

Comment: Please excuse the way I labeled it using my code. I added the  "----------------JUDGE 1 ROUND 1---------------" to know where I was in the code when it worked

Comment: I sent you a message